Executing Static Resources within LWC
I hope you're doing well. I'm attempting to use a third party library within my lwc. I've done my best to be abide by CSP policies. I was wondering based on the screenshots below, is there an obvious error I may be missing or next steps I should pursue.
Static resources within my org:

Trusted URLS & CSP Directives:

Developer tools console output for my component. "mapboxgl is not defined":

Also, according to console output, it appears the static resources were fetched properly:


HTML, CSS, JS source code:




Do you have Lightning Web Security enabled? If so, try turning it off, or if off, try turning it on. This code does have some references to workers, so I suspect it may not be compatible with LWC in Salesforce. You may have to try a different library. I've had moderate success with Leaflet. Also, there is a standard component, lightning-map that is guaranteed to work.

Please only use images to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way. Instead of using images for code, copy and paste the code as text into your question.
